# Have a div extend when an element from other div overlaps?

Tags: html, css

I have a div (lets call it header), and another div (lets call is content). Now, the content div extends its height to its contents. Within header, i have an element that overlaps far into content, but content div doesnt extend with the elements overlapping from header. Heres the css i have so far:

```
.content {
height:auto;
}
```

Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/pgvZr/

Comment: You'll need to provide more details.  Maybe your html, a link to the working page, a jsfiddle demo, etc.

Comment: post all of the code inside of the content and for the content div itself

Comment: Is that the full CSS that you have? Sounds like the header is positioned or something more than that is going on. A sample of the html used would be helpful too.

Comment: It sounds like a floating or absolute position problem, but without your HTML and CSS I can't be sure.

Comment: @kingjiv Added a jsfiddle link!

Comment: @simoncereska Added a jsfiddle link!

Comment: @DavidNguyen Added a jsfiddle link!

Comment: @Blake Added a jsfiddle link!

Comment: @JonahKatz Can you clarify your intentions? You want the brown box in the header to extend as it is, and have the blue background of content expand along with that brown box? If that's the case, you may have to restructure your html along with the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

`header` and `content` are siblings, so there is no way to have `content` expand with content that is part of `header` using just css

To solve your problem, you can:

- use javascript to calculate the height `content` should have and set it dynamically
- put `header` inside `content` and remove the fixed height of `content`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your "content" div isn't being pushed down is because you have a height set on your "header" div. So, relative to your "header" div, your "content" div is starting 100px down. If you don't set the height, then the "header" div ends up being the height of whatever is contained within it.

Take a look at this fiddle... simply removed your `height: 100px;` off the header and it accomplishes what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/pgvZr/4/

**Edit**: If you're adding content to the header and want it to be part of your content div (i.e have your content div grow with the header_inner text), then you should probably just move it into the content div. Otherwise, then you shouldn't specify the height on the header, and let it automatically push your content div down when you add the header_inner like my fiddle does.

Comment: This is right, but I'm not sure by his explanation if that's his intention. I think he wants to the blue content area to expand with it, which would take more than this.

Comment: So, the content isn't just being pushed down, but instead, it's growing in height along w/ the header?

Comment: Yes, it reads to me like that's what they want, waiting for them to reply. Sounds like jeroen may have gotten it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand the issue. You want to extend content height by adding text to header_inner?

Comment: why can't you have header_inner inside .content?

Answer (score -2):

That's because the child div has a higher z index than anything else, meaning its stacked way on top of everything and it doesn't participate in the document "flow" due to its positioning. I suggest use JQuery to calculate and set its height based on the heights of the other two divs.

Comment: No, z-index doesn't influence content interaction between child and parent (i.e. `#header` and its content).  An absolutely positioned element won't interact with anything (apart from stacking above/below it). Same is also true for floated children - they don't influence the height of their non-floated parent without a clearing element.